# How to calculate the length (in pixels) of a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to calculate the length (in pixels) of a string in JavaScript?

Comment: Where is the string held? Unless it is on the page, you can't get a rendered size. What happens if it is a long string and wraps over more than one line?

Comment: Need to calculate the length of the pixel rows and if it is greater than the width of the element, then change the line (to append an ellipsis) and return a string that will fit into the element.

Comment: You might be interested in my answer from there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660052/ellipsifying-the-text-in-a-yui-datatable/3664168#3664168

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the new information about your wanting to append an ellipsis for text overflow, I think the text-overflow CSS property is a better approach.  See this article on quirksmode for more information: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html

Answer (score 4):

you can use simple code

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "11px Arial";        
var width = ctx.measureText(str).width;
```

Answer (score 1):

A working example of simshaun's suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/tycjf/2/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to write it into a span on the page, get the width, and then delete the span.  Also, it's relative to whatever font-size the span inherits.

Comment: What happens if the line wraps?

Comment: It shouldn't assuming you setup the styles on your span tag correctly.