# Get string length in pixels using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, pixel, string-length

I want to know exact length in pixels of String i.e. "Hello World".

It should not be length of my container.

Any Help???

Comment: *"It should not be length of my container."* Pick the right container (e.g., a span with no padding) and there's no difference.

Answer (score 9):

Put your text in a `<span>` and use JavaScript to measure the width of your `<span>`.

HTML:

```
<span id="text">Dummy text</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
var textWidth = document.getElementById("text").clientWidth;
```

jQuery:

```
$('#text').width();
```

Comment: This does not work if the `span` has a CSS style which sets its width to `100%` for example!

Comment: You're right @Andry. Except `span` is per definition an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements). This means that you cannot define its width without changing its display to e.g. `block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: Also, another good answer mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558114/5864984.

Answer (score 5):

You can create some inline element (`span`, for example), set your string as element's content (`innerHTML`), insert it into document (append to some element) and get it's width (`clientWidth`).

There is no other way to measure length of string in pixels because it depends on font style.

Answer (score -1):

Since the pixel length of the string will change depending on independently applied CSS attributes such as font and weight and size, I can't see this being possible in JS.